# How to create a new dataframe according to it column name where the value is existed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
 Index   0   1   2
     0   0   1   0
     1   0   0   1
     2   1   0   0
     3   0   0   1
```

How do I create a new dataframe according to it column name where the value is existed or when the value = 1 ?

Expected output:

```
 Index   type
     0    1
     1    2
     2    0
     3    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) if only `1` or `0` values in columns:

```
#if Index is not column, but index
df['type'] = df.dot(df.columns)
#if Index is column or necessary omit first column
#df['type'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:])
print (df)
       0  1  2 type
Index              
0      0  1  0    1
1      0  0  1    2
2      1  0  0    0
3      0  0  1    2
```

Solution also working correct if no `1` value per row, then return empty string:

```
df['type'] = df.dot(df.columns)
print (df)
       0  1  2 type
Index              
0      0  0  0     
1      0  0  1    2
2      1  0  0    0
3      0  0  1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```
_, df['type'] = np.nonzero(df.values)

print(df)

   0  1  2  type
0  0  1  0     1
1  0  0  1     2
2  1  0  0     0
3  0  0  1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's seems like dummies. you can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```py
>>> df['type'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df
   0  1  2 type
0  0  1  0    1
1  0  0  1    2
2  1  0  0    0
3  0  0  1    2
```